# Slackware - c compiler works no

Tags: linux, gcc, slackware

I am new in slackware,
After clone postgresql 9.4 I start installation from direction at ./configure 
I got output
.
.
.

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/src/postgresql':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

after that I check gcc version:

```
root@li442-162:/usr/src/postgresql# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
```

My question  is how can run gcc compiler..?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have gcc installed? Right version ?

Comment: thanks for answer, i don't know how check the correct version of gcc I search in google but not found the answer.